# [fatal-error]: Redundant tag detected, aborting

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

While surfing on Stack Overflow I encountered a [fatal-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fatal-error). Here are the error logs I collected:

> Fatal error log started ...
>
> - **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?**
>
>   Not to a meaningful extent. "fatal error" comes from many places, and this word (phrase) does not carry any useful information, not even when combined with another tag.
> - **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
>
>   Surely a "fatal error" of a program *may* be on-topic here, but that depends a lot on the actual content of the post. For example, no one would agree that the following "fatal error" is accepted:
>
>   > Windows has encountered a **fatal error** and cannot continue. Please reboot your computer.
> - **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
>
>   Attempting to process highest-voted questions from https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfatal-error%5d%20is%3aquestion...
>
>   ```
>   fatal error: no meaningful information detected
>   ```
> - **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
>
>   Absolutely no. There are so many kinds of fatal errors that
>
>   ```
>   fatal error: inconsistent meaning, cannot continue
>   ```
>
> End of fatal error log. Please contact the Meta community for further assistance.
>
> Abort.

Can we fix this by eliminating all [fatal-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fatal-error)s from Stack Overflow? We've already got rid of [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) and blacklisted it.

Comment: Unlike [tag:error], There is a well delineated meaning and a context: **An error that causes a program to abort, regardless of the programming language**. There is a border here unlike the errors tag.  [Fatal errors are called that, because they are fatal. You can't recover from them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277387/). You say *Absolutely no. There are so many kinds of fatal errors that "fatal error: inconsistent meaning, cannot continue"*. The "cannot continue" part is the consistent meaning across all all languages including this post.

Comment: @TheMaster Your argument can apply to almost every burnination request, e.g., [the one about [user]](/q/268187). That it has a consistent meaning is not *sufficient* for a tag to be kept.

Comment: It fails criteria 1 too. It is not ambiguous. A clear well delineated border and seems to make good sense with [php] based on your top posts. Preferably [php] experts should weigh in.

Comment: Even without [php], it seems to provide good info(but the same meaning) when combined with other tags: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfatal-error%5d%20is%3aquestion%20-%5bphp%5d